# Can anyone tell me why before not working on styled components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm try to use `before` on style components on React but it's not working. Without `before` background image shown but after adding this `before` background image not showing;

```
import styled from  'styled-components'
export const Container=styled.div `
&:before {
content:'';
top:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
position:absolute;
background-image:url(${({bg})=>bg});
background-size:cover;
}
`;
```

Comment: Try to give width and height to the before css property. It will work

Comment: `left:0px; right:0px` means the pseudo-element has no width, so how would you see the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ::before with double ":" Also give some height/width